# Equivalence of definitions of quantiles

Tags: quantiles, definition

Let us define the concept of quantile of order $\tau$ of a random variable $X\in F$ in two different ways:

**Definition $1$**: $c_\tau$ is said to be a quantile of order $\tau$ if and only if $lim_{x\to c_\tau^-}F(x)=F(c_\tau^-)\leq \tau \leq F(c_\tau)$. (Note that we are considering the most general definition of a quantile).

**Definition $2$**:  $c_\tau$ is said to be a quantile of order $\tau$ if and only if it $c_\tau$ minimizes the function $g(a)=\mathbb{E}[\rho_\tau(X-a)]$, where $\rho_\tau(x):=x(\tau-I_{\{x<0\}})$ is the quantile loss function.

Now, if the distribution $F$ happens to be absolutey continuous, one can easily prove the equivalence of the previous definitions by solving $g^\prime(a)=0$. However, in a more general setting $g$ may not be differentiable, so we cannot proceed this way.

My question is: Is there an *easy* proof of the equivalence of definitions $1$ and $2$?

Or more generally: Is this even true when the distribution is not continuous?

Comment: What does "$c_{\bar{\tau}}$" mean?

Comment: @whuber It's the left limit of F in $c_\tau$.